# Selenium Webdriver to read data from Excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario like different parameters, and variables in my methods should take data from an Excel sheet and and take its value. For example, there is a variable like countryname and in Excel sheet its the 8th column with a  list of country names. So when i run the code the first time, countryname variable should take the 1st cell value in 8th column and the next time i run the code it should take the 2nd cell's value in 8th column. Similarly there are other variables which should take data from Excel sheet. How do i automate this scenario in java?

Comment: Use Apache POI or JExcel to read the excel file

Answer (score 1):

You can add Apache POI jar files in your project for using Excel(XLSX) files.
Also, attaching a sample code for your reference

```
void readXLSXFile(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream(fileName);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);

        XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheetAt(0);//you can change the value to index value of your required sheet
        Iterator<Row> rows = ws.rowIterator();

        XSSFRow row;            
        while(rows.hasNext())
        {
        row=(XSSFRow) rows.next();
        XSSFCell cell=row.getCell(7);//8th cell of the row
        String CName= cell.getStringCellValue(); //getting the cell value as string

        countryNames(CName);// Your method for passing the country name to the method for your requirement
        }

        wb.close();
    }
```